# plotting multiple lines with text at end of line in matlab

Tags: matlab, text, plot

I have some matlab code I have created for plotting multiple lines in the plot. However it does not seem to plot the text at the end of the line like I was hoping for. Does anyone have an idea of a way to make easier and why it might not be working.

```
format long;
options = optimset('TolFun',1e-12);
vfb = -0.9;
fT= 0.026;
fF = 0.4591431;
gamma = 0.2377589;
datafile = fopen('quiz3p2bresults.text','w');
if datafile == -1
    error('Error opening data file!');
end


fprintf(datafile, '%s\t %s\n', 'Vgb', 'PSIL')
vgb = 1:0.5:2;
vgb = vgb';
vdb = 0:0.1:1.5;
vdb = repmat(vdb,3,1);
eqn = @(psiL) (vgb-vfb-gamma*(sqrt((psiL-vdb)/fT)));
result = fsolve(eqn,vgb,options);
plot(vdb,result(1,:),'r',vdb,result(2,:),'y',vdb,result(3,:),'g');
text(max(vdb), max(result), num2str(vgb));


fclose(datafile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
text(max(vdb), result( : , max(size(result)) ), num2str(vgb));
```

You might also want to change the plot to

```
plot(vdb(1,:),result(1,:), ...
```